# Looping through a vector from begin to end get looped more than it should be

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, iterator

I'm trying to create a function where 2 already sorted vector merge with each other in an attempt to do the merge sort as optimized as I can. The code is as followed:
(Added some lines just for the sake of readability.)

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> Merge_Indexed(std::vector<T>& a, std::vector<T>& b)
    {
        for(auto it=b.begin(); it<b.end(); it++)
        {
            for(auto it2=a.end()-1; it2>=a.begin(); it2--)
            {
                if(*it>*it2)
                {
                    a.insert(it2+1, T(*it));
                std::cout<<"Case 1\n";
                    break;  
                }
                else if(*it<*it2&& it2==a.begin())
                {
                     a.insert(it2,T( *it));
                     std::cout<<"Case 2\n";
                     break;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout<<"Case 3\n";
                }
                
            }
            for(int x: a)
                {
                    std::cout<< x<<" ";
                }
            std::cout<<"\n******\n";
        }
        return a;
    }
```

But the problem is for the given 2 vectors:

```
std::vector<int> a= { 5,7,8,10 };
std::vector<int> b= { 2,4,9,11 };
```

The result is:

```
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 2
2 5 7 8 10 
******
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 1
2 4 5 7 8 10 
******
Case 3
Case 1
2 4 5 7 8 9 10 
******
Case 1
2 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 
******
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
2 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 
******
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 1
2 4 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 
******
Case 3
Case 3
Case 3
Case 1
2 4 4 5 7 8 9 9 10 11 
******
Case 3
Case 1
2 4 4 5 7 8 9 9 10 11 11 
******
2 4 4 5 7 8 9 9 10 11 11
```

I couldn't troubleshoot it because the only vector that getting extended was `vector a`, it should be printed out only 4 times (duo to the size of `vector b`) even when the inside part were wrong. And above that it was not entirely duplicated, the first element `b[0]=2` got straight out ignored in the second "loop" as i was checking the insert condition, not to mention it didn't bother to print the last `******` line. Can anyone help me with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: didn't really understand the code, but why not merge the input vectors into a third, initally empty vector, and return that?

Comment: The code is just broken. Start from this simple consideration: A merger of two sorted `vector`s of sizes *N* and *M* must take O(*N* + *M*) time, not O(*N²* × *M*) like in your case. Start by fixing this obvious discrepancy. (If you’re wondering where the **²** comes from, just consider what `insert()` does.) The basic synopsis (albeit not hugely efficient either) should be to avoid `insert()` and instead take a third `vector`, then optionally `c.reserve(a.size() + b.size())` and then merge `a` and `b` into `c`. You would need a `list` to use `insert()` reasonably.

Comment: `for(auto it2=a.end()-1; it2>=a.begin(); it2--)` This loop is very likely to exhibit undefined behavior when it executes `it2--` while `it2 == a.begin()`